# Do all servers equipped with sftp have scp?

Tags: ssh, sftp, scp

I'm wondering if I can make the assumption that I can get a file using scp on any server that I could get the file using sftp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mostly, yes. Both sftp and scp are file transfer protocols over ssh, and sftp is a more recent feature than scp, so while there are a few older setups with scp but no sftp, the converse would take some deliberate configuration.

However, it is possible for a server to allow sftp but not scp. One reason I can think of to configure a server this way is if you want to allow a single service over ssh, for simplicity's sake: sftp and scp provide the same level of access security-wise, but sftp is more convenient, so sftp is the preferable choice.

In other words, if the server can sftp, it can scp; but it might allow sftp and forbid scp.

Answer (score 3):

Servers that have OpenSSH (which includes most *nix servers) run SFTP as a separate subsystem under it. It is feasible to disable just the SFTP subsystem, leaving only SSH and SCP available. See the `sshd_config(5)` man page for details.

Answer (score 0):

`scp` comes with `ssh`. I'm not sure `sftp` is necessarily a part of it.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't assume that.

`scp` depends on `SSH` being available, which is not linked to `SFTP` being available.

~~edit: more details~~

`ssh` lets you do more than just copy files.  It will allow you to run commands.  So it is very easy to imagine a server that would allow you to sftp, but would not allow you to ssh.

Comment: Doesn't the S in SFTP stand for SSH?

Comment: more or less, yes, SFTP is just a more recent implementation of SCP, but SFTP is not run over SSH, it is a completely different protocol.

Comment: @MaQleod, @David: [SFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_file_transfer_protocol) is an FTP-like protocol over SSH. You seem to have it confused with [FTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS), which is a modification of FTP to use SSL. SFTP is carried over SSH; FTPS is independent.

Comment: @Gilles just because SFTP (as a technology) is based on ssh, doesn't I can ssh onto any server I can SFTP to.  Plenty of our clients use SFTP to transfer files to us, but none of them could ssh to the same server.